# Hibernate :How does strategy GenerationType.Table works?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

My Account entity **Primary key** is generated using **GenerationType.Table** stratergy.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE , generator="tablegenerator")
@TableGenerator(name="tablegenerator", table="ifinances_keys", pkColumnName="PK_NAME",valueColumnName="PK_VALUE")
@Column(name="ACCOUNT_ID")
private Long accountId;
```

I have defined a table ifinances_key to store this generated key and after persisting data , the following key is generated :-

**Ifinances_Key Table**

```
 PK_NAME,   PK_VALUE
 ACCOUNT    8
```

**My Account Table** has the following data :

```
ACCOUNT_ID | Rest of the columns ---->
200
300
350
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT * FROM account a natural join ifinances_keys b ;
```

I am getting all the data ie :

```
ACCOUNT_ID | Rest of the columns ---->
200
300
350
```

Please explain the internal working of this strategy and how this Join is working?

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? What are you trying to achieve with this query? If you don't understand how the query works, why are you using it?

Comment: i am not getting how 200 , 300 etc is generated and how natural join is working , as there is no common column between ifinances_key and account. I am new to hibernate and i want to learn this strategy for generating primary key

Comment: Well, forget about this SQL query. I don't even know why you're executing it in the first place. You're getting 200, 300, etc. because the generator, to be more efficient and cause less contention between transactions, doesn't increment the value every time an ID is requested. It increments it (from 7 to 8, for example), and then keeps a block of available IDs (from 700 to 799, for example) in memory. It's only when this block is exhausted that it gets and increments the next value from the table.

Comment: Thank you. How do we use this i-finances key to get our account data?

Comment: You don't. Accounts are identified by a primary key, and you use that primary key to identify an account. The primary key is stored in the account table. Whether it has been generated by a table generator, a sequence generator, a UUID of anything else doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Thanks alot. But I can't get, why do we use table generator then?

Comment: Well, to generate unique primary keys, just like any other ID generator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110730/discussion-between-user2332505-and-jb-nizet).